# Bad Base - 64 Error when trying to send an Image

Tags: java, android, wifi

I am looking to share a screenshot of a page between two devices. The screenshot is stored in a Bitmap and then I am converting it to a byte array which is then converted to a String in Base 64. The String is then sent over to a handler which will display the image. After I try to decode the image it is giving me a: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bad base-64

I have already tried to send the images in different ways and have tried all the different Base 64 methods such as Base64.DEFAULT, URLSAFE, NOPADDING etc...

Here is where I am creating the screenshot and sending:

```
Bitmap b = 
Screenshot.takescreenshotofRootView(MainActivity.imageView);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100,baos);
byte[] bytea = baos.toByteArray();
String temp = Base64.encodeToString(bytea, Base64.DEFAULT);
sendReceive.write(temp.getBytes());
```

This is where I am handling that data

```
Handler handler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
@Override
public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
switch (msg.what) {
   case MESSAGE_READ:
       MainActivity.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitm);
       byte[] readBuff = (byte[]) msg.obj;
       String tempMsg = new String(readBuff, 0, msg.arg1);
       byte [] encodeByte = Base64.decode(tempMsg,Base64.URL_SAFE);
       Bitmap bitms 
    = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte,0,encodeByte.length);
       MainActivity.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitms);
       break;
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be getting an OutOfMemoryError without realizing it, rendering your base64 string invalid.  You should wrap your code with a try/catch block to see if that is happening.  Here is an example in some code of mine:

```
    String imageString = "";

    try {
        if (this.theBitmap != null) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            this.theBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            byte[] bytes = stream.toByteArray();
            imageString = Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
        }

    }catch(OutOfMemoryError E){
        Log.e("MyApp", "Out Of Memory error");
    }
```